# UFW rules disappear after manually adding them to user.rules?

Tags: 16.04, firewall, ufw

I need to add rules to ufw by editing the user.rules for some reason, when I add rules to it and do `sudo ufw reload`, the rules are gone. Any reason why this happens and how can I add rules by manually editing the `user.rules` file?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create

Answer (score 8):

I just bumped into this scripting a ruleset for automating a host build.  ***The problem is with how UFW validates `/etc/ufw/user.rules`***

Merely manually adding a rule to `/etc/ufw/user.rules` such as:

```
-A ufw-user-output -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Will get purged when the ruleset is sanity checked when UFW starts **WITHOUT** the accompanying comment:

```
### tuple ### allow tcp 80 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 out
```

So in order to manually add a rule allowing TCP/80 that survives a reload of UFW would be:

```
### tuple ### allow tcp 80 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 out
-A ufw-user-output -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

### PLEASE NOTE:

The comment prefacing the manually added rule CANNOT BE arbitrary: it must be the comment UFW generates when you add a rule via the CLI.  In this example using TCP/80 that would be:

```
sudo ufw allow http/tcp
```

## Validating this solution:

### Steps to reproduce the **FAULT**:

- `sudo ufw disable`
- `sudo vi /etc/ufw/user.rules`
- Add `-A ufw-user-output -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` WITHOUT comment
- save and close ***/etc/ufw/user.rules***
- `sudo ufw enable`

Your manually added rule will be **PURGED**; it will not survive a restart of UFW

### Steps to recreate **SOLUTION**:

- `sudo ufw disable`
- `sudo vi /etc/ufw/user.rules`
- Add `### tuple ### allow tcp 80 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 out`
- Add `-A ufw-user-output -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`
- save and close ***/etc/ufw/user.rules***
- `sudo ufw enable`

Your manually added rule will **PERSIST**

Yes, absolutely insane that a rule with correct syntax which is not prefaced with a comment will fail validation and get purged.  How ironic for a firewall interface professing to be **UNCOMPLICATED**  ;-).

This drove me bananas.  Hope this solution saved other people grief-

Comment: Great analysis. Furthermore: the data in the comments do not appear to be completely validated. eg: one can change the IP-address range in the comment associated with the `-s` parameter in an associated `iptables` rule, and `ufw status` will list what is in the comment and not the actual rule. However, if one sufficiently changes the syntax of the comment line (I replaced `allow` with `blah blah`) one might receive something like a `WARN: Skipping malformed tuple: [...]` message in `ufw status` (or at least I did) and the resulting `iptables -nvL` listing still showed the correct settings.

Comment: Clarifying: it appears a comment line can be any legal statement that's parse-able by the ufw system, even if said comment line has not correlation with it's `ip[6]tables` paired command/rule.

Comment: @F1Linux had another good answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/980290/144798

Answer (score 7):

If you add your custom rules in /etc/ufw/before*.rules or after*.rules instead, it will not disappear after a reload.

When valid **ufw** commands are entered on the shell, i.e., custom user rules, they go into /etc/ufw/user*.rules files, and those persist.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ufw allow 22/tcp
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
root@ubuntu:~# grep tcp.*22 /etc/ufw/user*.rules
/etc/ufw/user6.rules:### tuple ### allow tcp 22 ::/0 any ::/0 in
/etc/ufw/user6.rules:-A ufw6-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
/etc/ufw/user.rules:### tuple ### allow tcp 22 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
/etc/ufw/user.rules:-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
root@ubuntu:~# iptables -L -n | grep dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
```

If you edit user*.rules directly, added rules (if valid) will be loaded in with **ufw reload** but will not persist at the next restart of the ufw service.

Therefore, add your custom rules in /etc/ufw/before*.rules or after*.rules instead.

References:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/728128

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Comment: Yes, this is generally how UFW was envisioned, but it's not actually true... if you include the required comments when editing `user.rules` then your rules will persist after system reboots and service restarts: https://serverfault.com/a/980290/144798