# Adding manual iptables rules to UFW

Tags: 18.04, iptables, firewall, ufw

I have a use case that needs iptables' ability to restrict a rule to a group id (--gid-owner). Ufw doesn't have support for this in its rule syntax.

From my experiments and reading online (e.g. [UFW rules disappear after manually adding them to user.rules ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006834)) it seems ufw will reject any manually-added iptables rules. That is to say, I can edit `/etc/ufw/user.rules` and add `-A ufw-user-output ... --gid-owner ...` but because it's not prefixed with a magic ufw-correct comment (since no such syntax exists), it's ignored and erased.

Do I have to pick one of ufw *or* iptables or is there a way I can get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
[Ubuntu: How to add an iptables rule that UFW can't create](https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create)

I added the netbios-ns helper to iptables, raw table using UFW config files under `/etc/ufw/`.
(Taken from [Arch Linux - Samba](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#Remote_control_of_Windows_computer) - source iptables command

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns
```

).
  This allows browsing an MS Windows network using Thunar as an example.

I added the translated syntax to the `/etc/ufw/after.rules` file, at the beginning, just after the initial comment block, see below:

```
#
# rules.input-after
#
# Rules that should be run after the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-after-input
#   ufw-after-output
#   ufw-after-forward
#

# netbios helper function allow browsing windows network
*raw
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns
COMMIT

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
[...]
```

Note: this syntax is the one used by iptables-save.

Then restart UFW.

Note that I had to insert at the beginning of the `after.rules` file, otherwise if I was appending at the end of the file, it was adding 3 times the same entry to the OUTPUT chain in the raw table once `ufw` was restarted.

It allowed me to avoid using the `/etc/ufw/user.rules`.  Perhaps it is an option that you can consider.

I hope it may help.